# Software & Updates showing wrong linux distribution

Tags: 16.04, software-sources

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a while back.

I just noticed that when I open `Software & Updates` the tab says `Debian Software` instead of `Ubuntu Software` as shown in the attached image:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's probably just a cosmetic discrepancy. If you wanna make sure everythin is fine, check /etc/apt/sources.list. Run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and share your results back... hmm... weird, on my synaptic screen it does show "Ubuntu Software"...

Comment: Question has been asked before here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/855437/software-updates-is-labeled-as-debian-software-and-i-cannot-get-ubuntu-repos#, but it has no answers. If no one can find a dup or answer by tomorrow, I will place a bounty there. I'm currently waiting for Darrel's update on that sources.list tho.

Comment: @SamuelSantana I actually tried to fix it recently by deleting it and trying to start fresh, it now only contains `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted main universe multiverse

# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse`
However, my PPAs under `other software` still persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list. To do this open your terminal and type in `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` (you can use the text editor of your choice), now remove everything and add:

## # Ubuntu main repos

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe`

## # Ubuntu security

`deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe`

## # Ubuntu updates

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe`

Save your changes and exit the text editor. Go to your terminal, type in: `sudo apt-get update`. Check if your problem was solved.

For more information on what I just told you to do, you can find it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).

Comment: Well, it still looks like it does above but now I can at least download from the Ubuntu repositories. Thank you Samuel.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If I have some time I'll look into that other cosmetic issue. Just one last thing: now you should be able to enable/disable repositories from the GUI, the "normal" way... am I right?

Comment: If you mean the `Software & Updates` GUI, yes I can open it and enable/disable repositories by going to the `Other Software` tab.